# Two models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two Models - Ksiazka.cs and Ludzie.cs and I have a View Wypozyczone.cshtml which presents Ludzie.cs.

Ksiazka.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }
    public string Autor { get; set; }
    public int Ilosc { get; set; }
```

Ludzie.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdKsiazki { get; set; }
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataWyporzyczenia { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataOddania { get; set; }
```

Ksiazka.id = Ludzie.IdKsiazki

I need to get Nazwa answering IdKsiazki.

Controler

```
public ActionResult Wypozyczone()
    {
        var model = _mojaBaza.Ludzie.ToList();
        return View(model);
```

My view

```
 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdKsiazki) //I want there Nazwa
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Imie)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nazwisko)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataWyporzyczenia)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataOddania)
    </th>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line, I need to get Nazwa answering IdKsiazki. And this line too, I want there Nazwa.

Comment: Sorry my english isn't good.

Comment: Check my answer bellow.

Comment: @Nkosi, the user does not mutiple models so this is not a duplicate of that question. The user has misworded their question.

Answer (score 1):

Create another class(some kind of viewmodel) which represents data you want

```
public class LudzieKsiazka
{
    public Ludzie Ludzie { get; set; }
    public Ksiazka Ksiazka { get; set; }
}
```

In controller create this "viewmodel"

```
public ActionResult Wypozyczone()
{
    var model = _mojaBaza.Ludzie.FirstOrDefault();
    var ksiazka = _mojaBaza.Ksiazka.FirstOrDefault(kz => kz.Id = model.IdKsiazki);

    var viewmodel = new LudzieKsiazka { Ludzie = model, Ksiazka = kziazka };

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

Then in view use this "viewmodel"

```html
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ksiazka.Nazwa)
</th>
```

Comment: This will not work because the `FirstOrDefault` will return the first record from `Ludzie` which does not neccessarily mean the `FirstOrDefault` from `Ksiazka` will be the related record. Essentially you are displaying 2 records which have nothing to do with each other. Plus the OP needs a `List` of `Ludzie` not one item.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, my example was only to display how "viewmodel" can be created. `Ksiazka.FirstOrDefault(kz => kz.Id = model.IdKsiazki)` will return related instance of `Ksiazki` for `model`. In addition OP have misleading example, where in controller he creates model as `List<Ludzie>` but in the view he uses model as instance of `Luzie`

Comment: No your code will not work even for one record. The OP does not need another model "viewmodel" to hold info from both. This is an xy problem.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, :), with "viewmodel" he will get access to related `Ksiazka.Nazwa` in the view - what OP was asking for. Besides your solution can be considered as same, only instead of viewmodel you added instance of `Ksiazka` straight in `Ludzie`. Which of course can be better solution from Entity Framework point of view. For example I prefer not to "combine" domain classes only for view purposes

Comment: I will not go back and forth with you but "domain" classes are not the same as  "entity model" classes. I hope you realize with your solution 2 trips to the database will be required. This is a simple one-to-one relationship but the user is missing that navigation. No worries mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more than a model on your view, please use [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx):

So your view should be some thing like this

```
@model Tuple<Ksiazka,Ludzie>
     <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Nazwa ) //I want there Nazwa
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.Imie)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.Nazwisko)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.DataWyporzyczenia)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.DataOddania)
    </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though, in your question, you have indicated 2 models, you do not need two models. Your problem is your current entity model does not have the one-to-one navigational property for the relationship.

Just listen to your code because it is telling you what it needs: Your view is asking for more information from another class so your view needs a model which has info from both of the models you have. In your `Ludzie` class you need a navigation property so it can hold the information for `Ksiazka`:

```
public class Ludzie
{
    // You need this property
    public Ksiazka Ksiazka { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you load `Ludzie`, you will have access to `Ksiazka`. Then in your view you can do this:

```
// You can access Nazwa
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ksiazka.Nazwa)
```

You can read more [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx) on navigation properties.

Comment: Ok i do what you wrote and when i add public Ksiazka Ksiazka to Ludzie.cs i get an error  "The model backing the 'BazaDanych' context has changed since the database was created." What can I do with it?

Comment: If you do not have data in the database, the easiest thing to do is to delete the database and it will recreate it. But if you have data then you need to do [database migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Ok now it's working, but i need to assign Nazwa to IdKsiazki. What i need to write in controler?

Comment: No you do not need to assign. EF will do it for you. What you have in the controller should work if you have the relationships properly configured as shown in the link I have in my answer where I say read more here. Do you need to display one record in your view or many?

Comment: I need to display list.

Comment: http://imgur.com/yWg8Uzl Nazwa is empty, but there http://imgur.com/a/R3p9n it's working. I will show you table http://imgur.com/a/Hh2C3 I have there idKsiazki what represent id from there http://imgur.com/a/tCx3X and i want to get Nazwa from this Id to my view.

Comment: Try `_mojaBaza.Ludzie.Include(x => x.Ksiazka)` to specifically tell EF to load that property. Make sure to import `using System.Data.Entity` or you will not see `Include` method.

Comment: _mojaBaza.Ludzie.Include(x => x.Ksiazka) It does not change anythink